# C++ imported library not compiled correctly

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I've included the headers of a static library (taglib.a to parse music files on the file system) in my Xcode project).

The library is written in C++. It seems the compiler in Xcode believes it's an objective-C library instead.

I get this compile error in the included header: taglib.h

```
Unknown type name 'namespace'
```

Usually for this kind of problem the solution is change the extension of the file to .mm to inform the compiler is not only objective-C, but in this case it's an header. And it's the header of an imported library, not even in my project tree.

How to solve this?

[image]

File using the library (#import "taglib/taglib.h")

[image]

Comment: The solution **is** to change implementation files from `.m` to `.mm`.  The error is occurring as a `.m` file is seeing the C++ header file.

Comment: @trojanfoe I think I wrote quite clearly in the question that I don't have access to the m files since this is a static library and the error occurs in the header instead.

Comment: Your question says "my Xcode project" so I assumed you had access to all the implementation files.

Comment: You probably include the header somewhere

Comment: @Theolodis What do you mean? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: What exactly the error log does say?

Comment: @trick14 exactly: Unknown type name 'namespace'

Comment: Which file is the compiler error in?  It's in a file ending with `.m`, right?  This file will need to be changed to `.mm` in order for it to work.  If you want to use a C++ library in Objective-C then you need to write Objective-C++.

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't understand. I wrote in the question it's an header file. I've also attached the screenshot, the file is taglib.h I don't understand why you keep saying me it's a .m file!

Comment: Yeah I've tried to specify the Type both C++ Header and Objective-C ++ (see in the screenshot the Type) but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: The compiler doesn't compile header files; it compiles implementation files that include header files.

Comment: @trojanfoe Ok, but that's a static library, it's already compiled right? I don't have m files, just binary. I've just linked it in the Project build settings.

Comment: I am assuming the compile error is in a (implementation) file that is part of your project that *uses* the static library, not in the static library itself.  If that is not the case then the issue is more complicated than you outline and more details are required.

Comment: @trojanfoe The library name is taglib.a, I've compiled it from terminal using cmake. The source code is this one: http://taglib.github.io

Comment: @trojanfoe Ok. The implementation file that is using the library only has this line of code: #import "taglib/taglib.h"

Comment: Tell me what details you need, thanks.

Comment: And the implementation file extension is?

Comment: @trojanfoe it's mm. The filename is: CBAddFilesController.mm

Comment: And Xcode confirms that it's an Objective-C++ source file?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, look, I've added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Well that doesn't make any sense; an Objective-C++ source file should happily import that C++ header file.  I am out of ideas.

Comment: @trojanfoe hey! I've solved. It was necessary to close and reopen xCode :( . Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by rebooting xCode.

Comment: How often do you need to restart Xcode?  Every time you create a new implementation file?  I think it's highly unlikely this solved the issue with including a C++ header file into an Objective-C++ implementation and makes me think you were changing things with the project as we exchanged comments on your question.  At least I've never had to restart Xcode when using a C++ library in Objective-C++...

Comment: Yeah this answer really didn't capture any of the solution... the solution was changing the compilation unit to C++/ObjC++ and that didn't take place until after you rebooted Xcode, because of a defect in xcode

Comment: Agreed; I believe the OP did not want to admit that my very first comment solved the issue :D  (Also doing a *Clean* would probably have avoided the need to restart Xcode).

Comment: @GradyPlayer Hey guys, I really don't want to continue with this debate. But if you ready my question you can see that I *already" have changed the .m extension to .mm. And I've posted the question *after* renaming it. Your solution was already in my question (see the last screenshot).

Comment: @trojanfoe Don't worry I can admit you know your stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Set it as C++ header. It will be fine.

[image]

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the question.

Answer (score 0):

where you are seeing the error, the file that is including the offending .h that file must be compiled with a c++ compiler, so if you have main.m you need to change it to main.mm - if you have foo.c you need to change it to foo.cpp - this isn't free, because now you live in c++ land for that compilation unit... so another approach is to make a ObjC++ class that handles the c++ library... then you have more pure c compilation units.

Comment: I just looked at it on my iPhone, so I didn't notice the 17 comments.

Comment: and if you do find the answer 17 comments later, you are allowed to answer your own question and accept it... to provide a good answer is more important than points, especially if a commenter solves your problem and never makes an answer.